# Symfony 3.4 - Transfert API stream file to client download

Tags: php, download, stream, symfony-3.4, guzzle6

An API sends me a stream containing a zip archive of several files that I choose by providing their ids in the parameter `SelectedIds` of my request.
I receive a PSR7 response that I pass to HttpFoundationFactory to return a Response that corresponds to what the Symfony controller should return.

*(the goal is to **download the zip** in the client side browser.)*

Here is the content of my controller method

```php
$client  = $this->getApiClient();
$user    = $this->getUser();
$idList  = [51,52,53];
$psr7ApiResponse = $client->post('/v1/get-zip', [
    'headers'     => [
        'Authorization' => sprintf('Bearer %s', $user->getToken()),
    ],
    'http_errors' => false,
    'json'        => [
        'SelectedIds' => $idList,
    ],
]);

$httpFoundationFactory = new HttpFoundationFactory();
return $httpFoundationFactory->createResponse($psr7ApiResponse);
```

It works perfectly locally but on the server I receive nothing, blank page. Would you know which way I should look because I have no error log, it looks like the stream is empty but I don't know how to check.

I tested the API with postman and it's ok ; my controller sends me back a 200 as well

Comment: Have you tried setting `http_errors` to true on production?

Comment: yes, no errors all is ok :'(  but the response seems to be empty

Comment: What is inside of `$psr7ApiResponse`? It should hold a status code and some headers that should hopefully have more information. Do you have error reporting in PHP turned on completely?

Comment: I have really no errors, it works very well localy but not online. All status code are 200. Very hard to debug. it looks like the content of the feed is not completely returned to my backend when I transfer it to the browser

Comment: Are there any other functions within the same API, which don't download ZIPs (e.g. a simple GET or POST), that you can test on PROD, to determine if it's an issue with the API as a whole, or isolated to this particular process? If the former, also confirm your API endpoint doesn't have IP whitelist restrictions stopping it sending your prod server responses. And can you post the response within `$psr7ApiResponse` please.

Answer (score 0):

Follow those steps in order to debug the problem:

**1. Check if the content of `$psr7ApiResponse` is valid and correct**

You are in a different environment. Maybe for some reason your server side script does not receive a valid answer. Maybe the authentication does not work. Print debug the answer you receive to some log file as detailed as necessary (use loggers:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html).

If the content or the resulting class of the call are not correct the problem is within the remote call communication and you have to debug that. This is most likely the case.

**2. Check if your client really understands the answer and check if the answer is correct**

Your client definitely should not receive a blank page (it indicates that the problem is 1).

Try to explicitly return a file by using `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File`.

You also can set certain ZIP headers to a `Response` object manually - at least for debugging:

```
    // set example variables
    $filename = "zip-to-download.zip";
    $filepath = "/path"; // maybe save the response to a temp file for debugging purposes
    
    $response = $httpFoundationFactory->createResponse($psr7ApiResponse);
    $response->headers->set('Pragma','public');
    $response->headers->set('Expires',0);
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control','must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Description','File Transfer');
    $response->headers->set('Content-type','application/octet-stream');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Transfer-Encoding','binary');
    return $response;
```